# Positioning text over a div

Tags: html, css, css-position, absolute

I am trying to position text in different places (top-left, top-center, top-right, bottom-left, bottom-center, bottom-right) over a responsive div/image. The width is responsive.

[image: Example layout I am trying to achieve]

Here is a fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/Fawn721/os01fnmt/

```css
.img-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.img-wrapper .overlay-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center
}

.img-wrapper .overlay-text p {
  position: absolute
}

.img-wrapper .overlay-text p.center {
  top: calc(50% - 1rem);
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: #000
}

.img-wrapper .overlay-text p.top-left {
  top: 0;
  left: 0
}

.img-wrapper .overlay-text p.top-center {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0
}

.img-wrapper .overlay-text p.top-right {
  top: 0;
  right: 0
}

.img-wrapper .overlay-text p.bottom-left {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0
}

.img-wrapper .overlay-text p.bottom-center {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0
}

.img-wrapper .overlay-text p.bottom-right {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0
}
```

```html
<div class="img-wrapper">
  <img class="lazyload" data-sizes="auto" alt="Mobile is the default image"
       src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=900%C3%97150&w=900&h=150"
       data-src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=414%C3%97150&w=414&h=150">
  <div class="overlay-text">
    <p class="top-left">&lt;p class="top-left"&gt;Top Left&lt;/p&gt;</p>
    <p class="top-center">&lt;p class="top-center"&gt;Top Center&lt;/p&gt;</p>
    <p class="top-right">&lt;p class="top-right"&gt;Top Right&lt;/p&gt;</p>
    <p class="bottom-left">&lt;p class="bottom-left"&gt;Bottom Left&lt;/p&gt;</p>
    <p class="bottom-center">&lt;p class="bottom-center"&gt;Bottom Center&lt;/p&gt;</p>
    <p class="bottom-right">&lt;p class="bottom-right"&gt;Bottom Right&lt;/p&gt;</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Probably easiest solution would be to use display: table and treat it like tabular data.

Answer (score 0):

`p` tags have default margins which are active in your fiddle. Add this:

```
overlay-text > p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/60xszm8b/2/

The remaining problem is that at the bottom the text will be aligned along its baseline. If you use all uppercase-letters, this looks okay. (You can use `text-transform: uppercase;` for that, although you might have to make the text size smaller then to fit everything in)